# How to input value in array to JSON array with for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to insert value in `myArray[]` and alert to show the value.

myArray:

```
var myArray = [{"id" : "obj_0" ,"src" : "bg2.png"}];
```

my function:

```
function getSet(sset_id){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
                var m = txt.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
                var w = m.split(' ');
                alert(w[0]); 
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<w.length;i=i+5){
                    myArray[i+1].id = w[i];
                    alert(myArray[i+1].id);
                }

                $("#frame").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
                myFunction();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","querySet.php?sset_id="+sset_id,true);       
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I convert `xmlhttp.responseText` into string and split it by space.

Then, I try to input value in `w[i]` to json array and alert it, but it not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON array pushing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383070/json-array-pushing)

Comment: Do you want to push values in array or push/modify values into object within array?

Comment: I want to push value from w array (not sure can call array or not) to myArray[]

Comment: So there's a chance that you're adding new objects to `myArray`? You wouldn't solely be modifying existing objects?